# Method Using Look-up Tables in Loop

Tags: loops, methods, lookup-tables

Background: 
I am self-taught and write code for my own use.  Because of this, my code has often been ugly.  While I still don't want to spend lots of time on complex error handling, since I will be the only user, I have decided to amend my ways and take baby steps toward "best practice" coding.  While looking on the meta, I found that this is apparently a bad word, not just on SO, but on any of the sites.  For reasons that seemed to boil down to "Stupid people usually use it", it was strongly recommended against.  However, if anyone had to maintain my code, I'm sure they would quickly decide there was some value to "best practice" and wish I had at least considered it.  With that info, here is my question:

Question:
I often encounter a situation (I can post not-yet-working code from the latest occurrence if it would help) where my procedure is bloated and I would like to break it into smaller procedures/methods.  The problem is: the bulk of my procedure is in a loop (using VBA, so I don't have access to some .NET alternatives), and there are either 1) many different variables used, or 2) large lookup tables.  My dilemma:

1. Leaving code as is makes it bloated, non-modular, and hard to maintain
2. Passing lots of lots of variables/tables to the method seems clunky and makes it hard to read.
3. Re-loading the tables would be a huge performance hit because of the loop
4. I've been told that if I use global variables, the gods will smite me.

So, how should I handle this situation?

Example: Importing/analyzing investment transactions.  For each transaction:

1. Lookup maximum previous ID# & assign next ID#
2. Search previous transactions for predecessor if any
3. Lookup account
4. Lookup transaction code (Buy/sell/dividend/etc) to determine accounting rules
5. Search description for fund names until a match is found
6. Lookup ticker symbol by fund name and share class
7. Lookup fees by ticker, date, and fee type
8. Lookup share balance and basis by ticker and account
9. Perform calculations using fees, shares, account type, basis, transaction code, dates, and dollar amounts
10. Add transaction record

As you can see, this involves multiple lookups which would be cumbersome to pass and a performance hit to re-read the tables into memory for each transaction.

Comment: Firstly: good on you for wanting to improve your code, and reaching out to expand your knowledge. However: I think this question is not a great fit for this site, because it's rather broad and theoretical. It *might* be a better fit on http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ but please check the Help Center on that site before posting it across.

Comment: @IMSoP - Thanks!  I tried looking on the meta for which site to post, but the top answer simply said "Don't ask about best practice".  Good idea to post on software engineering. What are the rules on cross posting?

Comment: [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info) (@IMSoP when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that)

Comment: @gnat I didn't know what the policy was, so waited for somebody who did (like you!) to answer the OP's question. The [linked FAQ post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-que) would be a better explanation, although it concentrates a lot on what you *shouldn't* do, and not what you *should*. In this case, I *think* the actual advice is "if you want to ask the question on another site, delete it here first". I think it's a flaw in Stack Exchange as a network that there isn't a more clear-cut system for this.

Comment: So, is the consensus, that I should delete this and ask it on softwareengineering instead?